# Android - OpticalFlow: calcOpticalFlowPyrLK & goodFeaturesToTrack return same points

Tags: java, android, opencv, computer-vision, opticalflow

I'm working on an Android video stabilization application!
I got some problem related with goodfeaturestotrack and calcOpticalFlowPyrLK functions 'cause the final output is the same points! 
I googled every single site regarding this but I wasn't able to solve it!
What's wrong with my code?

```
mRgba1 = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
mRgba2 = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
mGray1 = new Mat(mRgba1.size(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
mGray2 = new Mat(mRgba2.size(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
mView = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
initial = new MatOfPoint();
status = new MatOfByte();
err = new MatOfFloat();
mask = new Mat(mRgba1.size(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
prevPts = new MatOfPoint2f();
nextPts = new MatOfPoint2f();
Imgproc.goodFeaturesToTrack(mGray1, initial, maxCorners, 0.01, 0.01);
initial.convertTo(prevPts, CvType.CV_32FC2);
Video.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(mGray1, mGray2, prevPts, nextPts, status, err, winSize, 5, optical_flow_termination_criteria, 0, 1);
```

Then, when I show them:

```
Point[] pointp = prevPts.toArray();
Point[] pointn = nextPts.toArray();
for (Point px : pointp) 
{ Core.circle(mView, px, 15, circleColor); }
for (Point py : pointn) 
{ Core.circle(mView, py, 5, line_color); }
```

I got 2 different circles in the same position, and that's not good :(

Comment: Hi. How fast does the code work? I get only 3 fps with the camera.

Comment: Hi, i am doing the same thing and i am getting Assertion falied error "OpenCV Error: Assertion failed ((npoints = prevPtsMat.checkVector(2, CV_32F, true)) >= 0) in void cv::calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(cv::InputArray, cv::InputArray, cv::InputArray, cv::InputOutputArray, cv::OutputArray, cv::OutputArray, cv::Size, int, cv::TermCriteria, int, double), file /builds/master_pack-android/opencv/modules/video/src/lkpyramid.cpp, line 1110" any help

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is the videocapture passing the same image over and over again.
Did you try cloning the videocapture mats!
Also another thing to try , calcOpticalFlowPyrLK has 3 different ways that you can call . i would suggest using this one

```
Video.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(prevImg, nextImg, prevPts, nextPts, status, err, winSize, maxLevel)
```

:D

```
TermCriteria termcrit = new TermCriteria(TermCriteria.MAX_ITER|TermCriteria.EPS,25,0.03);
        Video.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(temp3, temp2, prevPts, nextPts, status, err, winSize, 5);
        //Video.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(prevImg, nextImg, prevPts, nextPts, status, err)
        //Video.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(temp3, temp2, prevPts, nextPts, status, err, winSize, 5, termcrit, 0, 1);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This section is for answers.  If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.

Comment: Yes, his problem is that he is not handling (prevImg, nextImg, prevPts, nextPts) correctly.

Comment: Just to clarify. If you had something like:

`mGray1 = mGray2;`

Change it to:

`mGray1 = mGray2.clone();`